# IS EBS payment gateway will support adaptive payments?

Tags: payment-gateway, paypal-adaptive-payments

I want to integrate EBS payment gateway to my site. i heard that paypal is supporting adaptive payments.

Is EBS payment gateway will support adaptive payments? can any one help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been working on EBS for quite a long time and till now I dont think it has adaptive payments as mentioned by paypal.com @ https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_APIntro